# Best Practice for Syncing Local Development With Staging Development

Tags: functions, theme-development, database, localhost, staging

My team and I focus on custom functionality locally using MAMP on a few Wordpress projects while our graphics guy who works on the styling, typography and layout settings works on the staging environment of the live site.

I am just wondering if there is a more efficient way for both our local and staging environments to be in sync. It is easy when there are simple functions added, or small stylistic changes but when we are both adding taxonomy terms to the database mixed with functionality and custom meta it can be a bit clunky. Right now we add individual functions to staging as we go from local to staging or take the document style changes from staging, add them to the local and wipe the staging which is becoming cumbersome.

We are currently moving towards a larger development team for upcoming projects and hoping to integrate a more scalable system for development. I was just wondering if anyone who has worked in a similar situation has any insights, it is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How are you doing it currently? Using git?

Comment: Highly recommend version control for your codebase but keeping the database in sync between environments is a WP challenge.  Try looking at what WP-CLI can do for you there.

Comment: Several approaches here if you haven't seen this yet:  https://www.sitepoint.com/synchronize-wordpress-live-development-databases/

Comment: Currently we are using git for the local development. We have not synced it with the staging site.

Comment: @TylerGiordani keep in mind you're going to need to be able to mark an answer as correct, aka the canonical answer that solve this, not just what worked best for you. This is a Q&A site, but this looks less like a question, and more like a discussion thread, perhaps it would be better suited on a forum?

Comment: These links look very helpful, thank you. I haven't used the CLI as well as the resources on sitepoint and can see it making a big impact on our development. I will seek out further advice through a forum.